# Two Button Columns on a GridView Control

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls

I have a grid view will two different button columns. I want  to perform a different action depending on what button the user presses. How in the SelectedIndexChanged event do I determine what column was pressed. This is the code I use to generate the columns.

```
grdAttachments.Columns.Clear();
ButtonField bfSelect = new ButtonField();
bfSelect.HeaderText = "View";
bfSelect.ButtonType = ButtonType.Link;
bfSelect.CommandName = "Select";
bfSelect.Text = "View";

ButtonField bfLink = new ButtonField();
bfLink.HeaderText = "Link/Unlink";
bfLink.ButtonType = ButtonType.Link;
bfLink.CommandName = "Select";
bfLink.Text = "Link";

grdAttachments.Columns.Add(bfSelect);
grdAttachments.Columns.Add(bfLink);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would help if you **give the buttons different CommandName properties.**

Here is an [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx) of reading `CommandName` in the `GridView_RowCommand` event, which specifically mentions your multiple-button situation:

```
  void CustomersGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {

    // If multiple ButtonField column fields are used, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName=="Select")
    {

      // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
      // property to an Integer.
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);    

      // Get the last name of the selected author from the appropriate
      // cell in the GridView control.
      GridViewRow selectedRow = CustomersGridView.Rows[index];
      TableCell contactName = selectedRow.Cells[1];
      string contact = contactName.Text;  

      // Display the selected author.
      Message.Text = "You selected " + contact + ".";

    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that answer as well after doing more searching.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

```
string commandName = e.CommandName.ToString().Trim();
  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
  switch (commandName)
  {
      case "showName":                   
          LClickName.Text = "You Clicked Show Name Button : \"" + row.Cells[1].Text + "\"";                   
          break;
      case "EditName":                   
          LClickName.Text = "You Clicked Edit Name Button : \"" + row.Cells[1].Text + "\"";                  
          break;
      default: break;
  }
```

Here is a sample for Multiple select Button in One Gridview

[Multiple Select Button In One Gridview](http://www.developersnote.com/2014/01/multiple-select-button-in-one-gridview.html)